# Странная компиляция

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Добрый день, есть у меня кусок кода, который я компилирую компилятором из VS 2008:

```
while(static int i = 0 < 5)
{
    i++;    
}
```

Я ожидал от него исполнения тела цикла 5 раз.
А вот что сделал компилятор:

```
    while(static int i = 0 < 5)
00401605  cmp         dword ptr [i (40701Ch)],0 
0040160C  je          wmain+2Fh (40161Fh) 
    {
        i++;    
0040160E  mov         ecx,dword ptr [i (40701Ch)] 
00401614  add         ecx,1 
00401617  mov         dword ptr [i (40701Ch)],ecx 
    }
```

1. Я ожидал от переменной **i**, что она, будучи статической, будет проинициализирована на стадии компиляции значением **0**. Она действительно была проинициализирована на стадии компиляции, но значением **1** (!?).
2. Мне абсолютно не понятно, почему условие цикла while, **i<5**, скомпилировалось как **cmp dword ptr [i (40701Ch)],0**
3. Исходя из листинга и пункта 1 очевидно, что программа уходит в бесконечный цикл.

Я не понимаю какого-то соответствующего момента в C++, или это баг компилятора?

Comment: i инициализорвалась результатом сравнения 0 < 5

Comment: точно, спасибо:)

Comment: В приведенном ассемблерном листинге я цикла вообще не вижу. Если ниже и есть jmp на cmp, то цикл все равно закончится при i = 0 (через переполнеие).

При хорошей оптимизации хороший компилятор вообще должен был все выбросить и инициализировать static i нулем. 

Если же к объявлению i добавить volatile, то цикл д.б. сохранен.

Comment: джамп ниже, следующей командой, я забыл его скопировать из-за того, что не акцентировал на нем внимание

Comment: Собственно в наличии jmp я не сомневался. 

Просто хотел акцентировать внимание на том, что на самом деле цикл не бесконечный и на оптимизацию из-за которой могут пропадать вставленные в код кратковременные задержки.

Особо не берите в голову, так все это, просто к слову пришлось

Comment: В любом случае, спасибо за комментарий.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в приоритете операций. Сравнение имеет бОльший приоритет, чем присвоение. Поэтому сначала происходит сравнение констант 0 и 5, которое компилятор производит на этапе компиляции, а далее его результат  (т.е. 1) присваивается переменной i.